# javascript variables in jQuery .load() parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I have to load multiple HTML parts in several divs with the class 'result' and a unique id.

```
$('.result').load('/check.php',
        {'id': this.id, 'url':'<?=$url?>'}
    );
```

A PHP script (check.php) will generate different HTML according to the parameters it gets (id & url). I want to pass this.id as a parameter, but the pages never get loaded.

this.id is a string right? If I replace this.id by say 'hello' it would work.

Comment: what do you expect `this` to be?  Unless this code is within a method of a JS object it'll be `window`.

Comment: it depends on context which cannot be seen from the code you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expecting `this.id` to be the ID of each individual `.result` element as passed to `.load`, that won't work.  Your code doesn't create a new context, so `this` will be whatever it was outside of the `.load` call.

This *should* work:

```
$('.result').each(function() {
    $(this).load('/check.php',
        {'id': this.id, 'url':'<?=$url?>'}
    );
});
```

because the `.each` call does set `this` to each of the selected elements, in turn.

Comment: I imagine the advantage to using a data object rather than `'?id=' + this.id` is that the correct delimiter will be used (`?` or `&`). Is this the case or is there more to it that than?

Comment: data object will make a POST and ?id= will give a GET method. This was not the issue, rather the fact that this.id wasn't clearly defined. Thanks @Alnitak

Comment: @Jasper the real advantage of using a data object is that it ensures that the contents are automatically URL encoded.

Answer (score 0):

`this.id` isn't necessarily a string.  The javascript keyword `this` is pretty [quirky](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html), so be careful with it.